# JFrame execution time adding JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm working with a `JFrame` adding `JPanel` instances dynamically in the following way:

```
private void addBox(int x, int y){
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
 panel.setSize(10, 10);
 panel.setVisible(true);
 panel.setLocation(x, y);
 this.getContentPane().add(panel);
}
```

The problem is, when I use `addBox` method, the `JPanel` instance does not appear in the `JFrame`. The only way I can see the box I need to manualy resize the window.

Note: I tried using `this.pack();`, but this did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` after such structural changes to the GUI.

Note that `setSize` and `setLocation` should preferrably be handled by the layout manager.

**Related link:**

- [jGuru: What is the difference between repaint() and revalidate() in Swing components?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=88716)

Comment: How I should use the layout manager to handled the size and location?

Comment: That depends on how you want the components to be layed out in the frame. If you want the box to have position `x,y` you should create a custom layout manager, set the content pane to use this manager, and pass x and y to the layout manager when adding the panel. Google for *java custom layout manager* for instance.

Answer (score 2):

What are the purpose of the boxes?

If they are purely visual, and you don't intend to add components to them, it would be better to define a `Box` class (or use a [Rectangle2D](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.html)) and draw or fill them at time of `paintComponent()`.

Alternately, draw them to the `Graphics` object of a `BufferedImage` and add the image to a `JLabel`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387194/java-applet-is-there-a-simple-way-to-draw-and-erase-in-a-two-layered-2d-scene/7403477#7403477).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This example showing [add/remove/pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988317/dynamically-add-components-to-a-jdialog/6989230#6989230) may help.

```
private void addBox(int x, int y){
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
   add(panel);
   //If there isn't another JPanel, then this way you'll occupy 
   //the whole JFrame area; by defalut, JFrame has BorderLayout,
   //and only one JComponent can occupy the central area 
   revalidate();
   repaint();
}
```

Comment: how do you know he hasn't done `getContentPane().setLayout(null)`?

Comment: @aioobe 1) yes only in case that there is `setLayout(null)`, 2) no for `setSize` and `setLocation`, because pretty ignored used LayoutManager and works in all cases

Comment: *...and works in all cases* -- Uhm, the values passed to `setSize` will be overridden by any layout-manager present (i.e. will only be in use until the component needs to be "re-layed-out"). Perhaps that's what you tried to say ;-)